# Convert polygons given as coordinate pairs to sf object

Tags: r, geojson

I load a `geoJSON` object into R with `jsonlite` as object `poly_shape`. `poly_shape` has 4 columns, one, called `geometry`, contains the polygon data in coordinate pairs. For example, the first row of `poly_shape$geometry` looks like this:

```
[[1]]
           [,1]      [,2]
  [1,] 27.81674 -82.05954
  [2,] 27.81499 -82.05964
  [3,] 27.81498 -82.05872
  [4,] 27.81484 -82.05872
  [5,] 27.81492 -82.05889
```

How can I convert this object into an `sf` object, because `st_as_sf` just returns

```
Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : no simple features geometry column present
```

Comment: whats the actual code you are using?

Comment: Why not just read your geoJSON directly with `st_read`?

Comment: When you say "load a geoJSON object" do you mean from a geoJSON file?

Comment: @AllanCameron: the geoJSON files contain a few errors I first need to fix, st_read unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: what errors does it contain? can you give an example?

Answer (score -3):

I recently wrote a small function to do exactly this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# create data.frame
df <-
  tribble(
    ~ lat,     ~ long,
    27.81674, -82.05954,
    27.81499, -82.05964,
    27.81498, -82.05872,
    27.81484, -82.05872,
    27.81492, -82.05889
  )

# write function
fn_convert_to_polygon <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    as.matrix(ncol = 2) %>% 
    as.numeric() %>% 
    matrix(ncol = 2) %>% 
    st_linestring() %>% 
    st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
    st_sfc()
}

# apply function
fn_convert_to_polygon(df) %>% 
  st_as_sf()
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 27.81484 ymin: -82.05964 xmax: 27.81674 ymax: -82.05872
#> CRS:           NA
#>                                x
#> 1 POLYGON ((27.81674 -82.0595...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't really do what the Q asked. First, the question has a list containing a matrix, not a tibble or a data frame. Your code actually converts to a matrix (twice) which would be totally unnecessary for the questioner.